# Javascript (how to check Id exist or not in IE7 Browser)

Tags: javascript

How do I check if Id exist or not in IE7 browser. Below is my code but it does not run successfully in IE7.

```
if(document.getElementById('Username') != null) { 
   alert("In"); 
}
```

When run this code comes true part and show alert box even though Id ('Username) does not exist.

Comment: why wouldn't this id exist in IE7?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `!= null` part, like this:

```
if(document.getElementById('Username'))
{
    alert("In");
}
```

Comment: ok.i remove the != null part and run on IE7 Browser..show same issue..it comes true part and show alert box...

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce. It must be something else in your code, not these lines.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery

```
if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version) == 7) {
  if ( $("#Username").length > 0 ) {
    //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: That's if you have jQuery, of course. And the browser check is rather unnecessary.

Comment: hi..but this code is not run  in mozilla firefox..i want to run this code in all browser like mozila,ie,opera,safari etc ..

Answer (score 0):

First if you are checking whether the id exist then

```
if(document.getElementById('Username'))
```

But if you checking whether (i presume its a textbox) the textbox is empty or not then

```
if(document.getElementById('Username').text ==null)
```